# Accessing XUL Elements using Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to manipulate the XUL elements in the Firefox add-on page using the Add-on SDK. I wouldn't mind using lower-level modules. I used DOM inspector to see the structure for the add-on page. It looks like this for the add-on page:

```
#document
--page (id='addons-page', windowtype='Addons:Manager', etc.)
----...
----hbox
----hbox
----etc.
```

So I tried this bit of code in exports.main:

```
let delegate = {
  onTrack: function(window) {
    console.log('window is being tracked: ' + window); // outputs [object ChromeWindow

    let doc = window.document;
    var addOnPage = doc.getElementById('addons-page');
    console.log(window.document.page);  // outputs undefined
    console.log(addOnPage);             // outputs null

    var xulElements = window.document.getElementsByClassName('addon-control');

    console.log('our elements: ' + xulElements); // outputs [object HTMLCollection]
    console.log('our elements length: ' + xulElements.length); // outputs length of 0
  }
};
var tracker = new winUtils.WindowTracker(delegate);
```

The first problem is that the window tracker only open when Firefox is first started. How can I get it to listen and wait for the add-on page to be opened?

The second problem (probably related to the first) is that getting the elements doesn't seem to be working (xulElements.length is 0).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. Add-on Manager doesn't usually open as a separate window so using `WindowTracker` is pointless. It is a page loaded into the browser.
2. You access the window before it has a chance to load to it isn't surprising that you don't see any elements.

Given that [`page-mod` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.2/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html) doesn't seem to work for this page, listening to the [`chrome-document-global-created` notification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Observer_Notifications#Documents) is probably the best solution. This code works for me:

```js
var observers = require("observer-service");
observers.add("chrome-document-global-created", function(wnd)
{
  if (wnd.location.href == "about:addons")
  {
    // Wait for the window to load before accessing it
    wnd.addEventListener("load", function()
    {
      console.log(wnd.document.getElementsByClassName('addon-control').length);
    }, false);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes this works. But for some reason manipulating the xul doesn't seem to work, I added: `var elements = wnd.document.getElementsByClassName('addon-control');


            console.log('get attribute: ' + elements[5].getAttribute('label'));
            elements[5].setAttribute('label', 'some label');` but nothing gets changed...

Comment: @Salami: That's an unrelated question but since you are already using DOM Inspector you can verify: a) that your code indeed changes the label on the correct element, b) that changing the label via DOM Inspector has the desired effect. I guess that you will figure it out by yourself if you try that. If not - create a new question and explain what you are trying to achieve.